# How to create a dynamic DelimitedLineTokenizer from MultiResourceItemReader current resource?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a directory with different csv files.

`data_1_status.csv` has 3 fields `ID`, `status1` and `status2` (no header). Blank status is also valid

```
2984,COMPLETED,COMPLETED
2985,COMPLETED,COMPLETED
2986,COMPLETED,FAILED
2987,,
```

`data_2_status.csv` has 4 fields `ID`, `status1`, `status2` and `status3` (no header). Blank status is also valid

```
16658,COMPLETED,COMPLETED,COMPLETED
16659,COMPLETED,COMPLETED,FAILED
16660,COMPLETED,FAILED,FAILED
16661,,,
```

From my database I know the number of statuses for `data_1` and `data_2` and I don't want to create a specific job/step for each `data_x` because I will add in database more `data_x` without developping more code.

## I exclude

I exclude usage of `delimitedLineTokenizer.setStrict(false)` with a list of fake fileds like:

```java
delimitedLineTokenizer.setNames("id", "steps[0]", "steps[1]", "steps[2]", "steps[3]", "steps[4]", "steps[5]", "steps[6]", "steps[7]", "steps[8]", "steps[9]");
```

because the mapping must fail and throw a FlatFileParseException if I have a missing field or an excess field and I have to make the difference between a missing field and an empty field:

```
2984,COMPLETED,COMPLETED      -> valid (3 fields)
2984,COMPLETED,COMPLETED,     -> FlatFileParseException (4 fields) excess
2984,COMPLETED,               -> valid (3 fields)
2984,,                        -> valid (3 fields)
2984,COMPLETED                -> FlatFileParseException (2 fields) missing
```

## How to improve?

I find a way to do it but I am absolutely not satisfied. The deprecated `getCurrentResource()` is triggering me, is there any alternative?

Of course `ResourceAware` can not be used because the item `StatusCsvLine` is not mapped yet.

```java
@StepScope
@Bean(name = "statusesItemReader")
MultiResourceItemReader<StatusCsvLine> statusItemReader() throws IOException {
    MultiResourceItemReader<StatusInputCsvLine> reader = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
    ResourcePatternResolver patternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
    Resource[] resources = patternResolver.getResources("file:/tmp/statuses/*_status.csv");
    reader.setStrict(false);
    reader.setResources(resources);
    // The UGLY part is here: reader.getCurrentResource() is deprecated but I have to push it
    // and I have to force push it with a callable because getCurrentResource() must be called during a Step execution (not the during the Bean initialization)
    FlatFileItemReader<StatusInputCsvLine> itemReader = statusFlatFileItemReader(() -> reader.getCurrentResource().getFilename());
    reader.setDelegate(itemReader);
    return reader;
}
```

```java
FlatFileItemReader<StatusCsvLine> statusItemReader(Callable<String> resourceNameCallable) {
    BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<StatusCsvLine> beanWrapperFieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
    beanWrapperFieldSetMapper.setTargetType(StatusCsvLine.class);

    DefaultLineMapper<StatusCsvLine> defaultLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<StatusCsvLine>() {
        @Override
        public StatusCsvLine mapLine(String line, int lineNumber) throws Exception {
            String dataType = resourceNameCallable.call().replace("_status.csv", ""); // data_1 or data_2

            
            //  conf: {
            //      dataType: "data_1",
            //      steps: ["step_1", "step_2"]
            //  },{
            //      dataType: "data_2",
            //      steps: ["step_1", "step_2", "step_3"]
            //  }
            //
            //  @Getter
            //  @Setter
            //  class ConfigData {
            //      private String dataType;
            //      private String[] steps;
            //  }
            
            ConfigData conf = configDataRepository.findByName(dataType);


            //
            //  @Getter
            //  @Setter
            //  class StatusCsvLine {
            //      private String id;
            //      private String[] statusSteps;
            //  }
            //
            //  I create the new tokenizer field names matching with StatusCsvLine class
            
            List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
            // I add the "id" field
            names.add("id");
            // I add the "statusSteps[x]" fields
            for (int i = 0; i < conf.status().length; i++) {
                names.add("statusSteps[" + i + "]");
            }

            // I create a new tokenizer
            DelimitedLineTokenizer delimitedLineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
            // I convert List<String> into String[]
            delimitedLineTokenizer.setNames(names.toArray(new String[0])); // which creates delimitedLineTokenizer.setNames("id", "statusSteps[0]", "statusSteps[1]", "statusSteps[2]")
            delimitedLineTokenizer.setStrict(true);
            
            // I update the tokenizer in live
            super.setLineTokenizer(delimitedLineTokenizer);
            
            // Then I call the mapper with its new custom tokenizer
            return super.mapLine(line, lineNumber);
        }
    };
    defaultLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(beanWrapperFieldSetMapper);

    return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<StatusCsvLine>()
            .name("statusItemReader")
            .lineMapper(defaultLineMapper)
            .build();
}
```

---

### Edit 1: based on Mahmoud answer

No, the `MultiResourceItemReader` is not designed to manage different format. So I won't use it.

I've decided to create the steps dynamically based on the configuration. It means the Job must be recreated at each execution (right?). And it works as expected.

I did it creating a "prototype" scope bean of my Job:

```java
@Bean(name = "statusJob")
@Scope("prototype")
Job statusJob() {
    SimpleJob statusJob = new SimpleJob("statusJob");
    statusJob.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    statusJob.setSteps(statusJobSteps()); // Dynamic steps creation
    return statusJob;
}
```

And my scheduler takes a new instance of the job this way:

```java
@Scheduled(cron = "${batch.scheduler.cron.status}")
public void statusJobScheduler() throws /*...*/ {
    jobLauncher.run(context.getBean("statusJob", Job.class), new JobParametersBuilder()
            .addLong("timestamp", System.currentTimeMillis())
            .toJobParameters());
}
```

At this point I have a bit lack of knowledges and don't know if my solution is clean.
I'm more satisfied than my previous "trick". However I don't know if Spring provides a solution to "recreate" the Job without the usage of "prototype", or if I can remove "obsolete" steps and add new ones from the existing Job (depending on my configuration changes). Do you know if I can do it in a better way?

Answer (score 0):

The `MultiResourceItemReader` is designed to read multiple file having the *same* structure. This is mentioned in the documentation here: [Multi-File Input](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#multiFileInput).

In your case, you are trying to use it to read files of different formats, which is the reason you are not able to achieve what you are looking for easily.

In my opinion, creating a custom reader would be a better option than trying to make that reader work for a case it was not designed for.

Comment: Correct, I tried to dodge the problem with `MultiResourceItemReader` despite it was not designed for. I'm a little bit afraid to create a custom reader (too specific or with bugs). So I feel more comfortable creating a job with multiple dynamic steps based on my configuration.

Comment: I edited my question with a new solution. I know it's not related to the original question anymore, but would you, please, make me a feedback about it in a new response? Thank you

Comment: `However I don't know if Spring provides a solution to "recreate" the Job without the usage of "prototype",`: This can be done with `@StepScope`. Any bean with that scope will only be created lazily at runtime and can be dynamically configured with the value that changes from run to run.